# Can you run a UIViewPropertyAnimator on viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to run a animation that changes the color of the view after a duration of 4 seconds but the animation skips to the end result rather than animating.

In this I am creating a "lightView" that will ease in and out from red to white once this ViewController is presented. I'm using SnapKit to set the constraints as well.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let lightView = UIView()
    lightView.backgroundColor = .red
    lightView.alpha = 0.33

    view.addSubview(lightView)

    lightView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(view)
        make.height.equalTo(view).offset(-70)
        make.centerX.equalTo(view)
        make.top.equalTo(view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.snp.top)
    }

    let dismissButton = UIButton()
    dismissButton.backgroundColor = Global.globalShared.hexStringToUIColor(hex: Global.globalShared.danger)
    dismissButton.setTitle("Dismiss", for: .normal)
    dismissButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dismissButton_Pressed), for: .touchUpInside)
    dismissButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5

    view.addSubview(dismissButton)

    dismissButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.width.equalTo(100)
        make.height.equalTo(30)
        make.centerX.equalTo(view)
        make.bottom.equalTo(view)
    }

    let viewColorAnimator: UIViewPropertyAnimator = UIViewPropertyAnimator(
        duration: 4.0,
        curve: .easeInOut)

    viewColorAnimator.addAnimations {
        lightView.backgroundColor = .white
    }

    viewColorAnimator.startAnimation()

}
```

In a different ViewController here is how the animated ViewController is presented:

```
@objc func startButton_Pressed(){
    //registerLocal()
    self.present(NoiseLightViewController(), animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Are you allowed to run an animation in the viewDidLoad? If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try running your animation in viewDidAppear

Answer (score 0):

Until your view has finished the layout process, no animations can be run. So you have to put the animation codes in viewDidAppear.